# Subversion to TFS migration

Tags: svn, tfs, tfs-migration

I'm trying to use the TFS Integration Platform to migrate my SVN repositories to my Team Foundation Server Repositories.

First i wasted much time on find out how to migrate SVN in TFS with this tool, because with the new Release (March 2012) there is no SVN Adapter within the installation.

So i tried to download a Beta version of TFS Integration Platform which already had the SVN Adapter, the problem is that i got an Error while discovering Files.

So, does anyone know where i get a TFS Intregration Platform version with an SVN Adapter on a stable version?

And don't just post this Link http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com, i already know that it exists.

Thanks (:

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timely Migration... well worth the investment.  I've used this tool for Star Team migrations, but they include SVN and their support is fantastic.

http://www.timelymigration.com/

Answer (score 2):

Have you already tried [svn2tfs](http://svn2tfs.codeplex.com/)?

> **What it does**
>
> Migrates a SubVersion 1.6.x (SVN) repository to Team Foundation Server
>   (TFS) 2010 replaying every action occurred in SubVersion.

Otherwise you may have a look at the [Timely Migration](http://www.timelymigration.com/) commercial tool.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes i already tried svn2tfs, but it always stucks anywhere in the code while waiting for another thread. I also wanted to define the path of the SVN (i just wanted the trunk folder in my TFS root), which several sourcecode changes it worked.. nevertheless the threading problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this tool (free) SVN2TFS:- http://svn2tfs.codeplex.com/

Now I have successfully migrated code from SVN along with revision history and folder structure into TFS2010.